# Cast function SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have a column 'Created date' of string type (which has values like 19-01-2022, 05/02/1992 etc). I need to write a query to get the data from this table Orders where created date is greater than Jan 1st 2019. How can I write the query using cast function?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: string type can be a number of different types, which do you mean ? But most important, why would anyone store a date in a string datatype?

Comment: That's a mess you are gong to have to write a lot of code that attempts to standardise the dates and even then if input truly is freeform you can't be sure that a 2 digit token is dd or mm or yy.  Do you have anything that might help such as country that the input relates to?

Comment: Another approach might be if you know the last order number prior to Jan 1st 2019 and the order number is sequential then comparing on that may do.

Comment: Your problem is how you store these values, if you get the values as 'string' then you should have converted them into a datetime and store it in the database in a DateTime2 datatype. You probably get your data in freeform, so you thought that it would be an easy solution to store it just like that, now you did not have to do that difficult convert. But, as you now have noticed, that first problem you had did not go away, it is back now. You just postponed it. The best solution is to alter the datatype to datetime2 and fix the input, it's either there or here, the problem remains the same

Answer (score 0):

if you have just two string formats i.e. dd-mm-yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy then you can get through inline query only.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE CONVERT(DATE,createdDate,103) >= '2019-01-01'
```

or if you passing search values in dd/mm/yyyy then

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE CONVERT(DATE,createdDate,103) >= CONVERT(DATE,'01/01/2019',103)
```

in case if you have more other types of string stored like mm/dd/yyyy then add one column to your table with datetime datatype. you only knowing the type of data in created date so you need to convert them into dates one by one. like for dd-mm-yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy you can convert to date.

Following is example of query for conversion

```
DECLARE @strdate VARCHAR(50)

SET @strdate = '19-01-2022'

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@strdate,103)

SET @strdate = '05/02/2022'

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@strdate,103)   

SET @strdate = '12/31/2022'

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@strdate,110)
```

you need to update newly added column from createddate column using update query and then apply your function on that

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET newcreatedDate = CONVERT(DATE,createdDate,103) WHERE newcreatedDate IS NULL
```

and perform search query

```
  SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE newcreatedDate  >= '2019-01-01'
```

or if you passing search values in dd/mm/yyyy then

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE CONVERT(DATE,newcreatedDate  ,103) >= CONVERT(DATE,'01/01/2019',103)
```